# Is this sentence grammatically correct? Is it a comma-splice if it's a list?

Tags: grammaticality, comma-splices

This is the sentence: "Many wore mere sweatpants and ragged t-shirts, several wore no shirts at all, and few carried backpacks."

My question: does having a comma after "t-shirts" make the sentence a grammatically incorrect/run-on sentence? Or is the grammar acceptable given that "several wore no shirts at all" is part of a comma separated list (i.e. x, y, and z)?